# How can we mark legend for a scatter plot based on color

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend, scatter-plot

I am plotting a graph to visualize the running time of a few sorting algorithms on different datasizes. The condition is that running time should be on y-axis and data size on x-axis.I plotted a scatter plot by taking run times of different algorithms against a data size and given each marking a different color. Similarly, I plotted for 3 other datasizes but with the same colors for different algorithms. I want to add a legend to the graph such that the user understands that this particular color points corresponds to this particular algorithm. I couldn't figure out a proper way for that. I searched a few scenarios online and they are adding legends based on different scatter plots. But,I want to add a legend for points based on color.

Also, for this scenario can you suggest a better plotting curve.

This is the code I used for graph generation.

```
def visualize_datasize(dataset):
    datasize=len(dataset)
    for i in range(4,0,-1):
        run_time=getRunTime(dataset,int(datasize/i))
        plt.scatter([int(datasize/i)]*5,run_time,color=['red','green','blue','yellow','black'])
    plt.xlabel('Size of the dataset')
    plt.ylabel('Run time')
    plt.title('Run time vs datasize for various sorting algorithms')
    plt.show()
```

[image: Scatter plot]

Comment: Please show the code you used to generate this plot.

Comment: Added the code in the question.

Comment: You could transpose the data, i.e. loop over the different algorithms and create a scatter of a singe color for each. Then defining a label within each scatter allows to easily get the legend automatically. Else, you can of course create your custom legend (`plt.legend(handles=..., labels=...)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest, most consistent way to do this is to make a scatter plot for each algorithm. Also, you probably want to be using the object-oriented interface for this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def calculate_runtimes(algo, data, sizes):
    if algo == 'name1':
        # return timings for algorithm 1 given data at given sizes
    elif algo == 'name2':
        # ...

algo_labels = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5']
sizes = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
algo_runtimes = {name: calculate_runtimes(name, dataset, sizes) for name in algo_labels}
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black']
x_positions = [len(dataset)*size for size in sizes]

for (label, runtimes), color in zip(algo_runtimes.items(), colors):
    ax.scatter(x_positions, runtimes, color=color, label=label)

ax.legend()
```